# Install a dependency and save to package.json for a sub-package in yarn workspaces

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am trying to use Yarn Workspaces for my app that I am splitting into multiple packages such that I can share code between the mobile and web version of the app. Let me explain what I am trying to do with an example.

Let's say I currently have a mobile app called `awesome-app`. I am refactoring it by taking out the shared code and creating three packages as follows:

```
awesome-web
awesome-mobile
awesome-shared
```

Let's say I want to add new functionality to `awesome-mobile` for which I have to install `depA` to `awesome-mobile`. How can I do that such that yarn only installs `depA` and updates the package.json for the `awesome-mobile`. I tried using command `yarn package <package-name> add depA` but it ended up installing all the dependencies again which I want to avoid.

Also, let's say I want to use `awesome-shared` in `awesome-web`. Is there a yarn command such that it installs and updates the package.json for `awesome-web` automatically. Currently, I do it by hand and then I do `yarn install` in the root folder which ends up installing all the dependencies again.